# Ubuntu 12.04.5, Lenovo T530 laptop with Dual monitors. Second Monitor is not recognized

Tags: multiple-monitors

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 because I gave up on 14. Only one of my dual monitors (both HP EliteDisplay E231) is working. When I go to System Settings > Displays I only see my laptop and the first monitor(vga), but not my second (dvi)

Checked out NVIDIA X Server Settings, also nothing

I did a clean install with ubuntu 12.04, I ran apt-get update. I have NVIDIA driver version 331-updates). I have a Lenovo T530 and was running Dual screens with Windows 7 before. Heres my xorg.conf file:
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    # The internal display might not be connected
    # to the nvidia card but we definitely want
    # to be able to connect external displays later
    #Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

I wish I could post screen shots but apparently I'm not allowed to just yet. Let me know if you guys need more info. Thank you.

Comment: Also detect display does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Dang, I'm not at work right now but I'm also using a Lenovo there and had similar problems with Mint Cinnamon.

AFAIR correctly you can use the Fn-Keys to put the Screen to an external monitor, might be Fn5 or Fn6.

This should most hopefully detect the third one. It sounds ridiculous, but I could only use the internal display and one external display, or shut off the internal one and use a second external display.

But I have to admit, I'm not sure if mine has a nvidia card in it. So it might be not the solution for your laptop.

Comment: Thank you! It looks to me that NVIDIA X Server Settings doesn't even recognize the screen that is working. In the X Server Display Configuration tab the Layout box shows "X Screen 0 (No Scanout)"  Also I turned off the laptop screen (at work I only use the dual external screens and have the laptop closed on a dock where all external devices are plunged into. Still only one screen displayed.

Comment: If I find the time tomorrow I try look for my xserver config and post it to you to try or at least compare.